# Select option selected live with $.post

Tags: php, select, post

I'm trying to add '`selected`' to a  element but the code doesn't execute at all.

Any suggestions why ?

The code is:

```
    $.post('./question_in_test.php',
          {
            questionId : vars[0]
          } ,
           function(data) { 
            $("#testQuestion > option").each(function () {  
                console.log("Something happens"); // Doesn't execute at all 
                if (this.value === data) {
                    $(this).prop('selected', 'selected'); 
                } 
            });
            console.log("NUmber id : "  + data + " vars[0] : " + vars[0] ); // Shows on the console 
         }             
    );
```

on the `PHP` page, I have a `select` which I have retrived from the database .

```
<select id = "testQuestion">
 <optgroup label="Category 1">
  <option>Option 1...</option> 
 </optgroup> 
 </select>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your options appear to be in `optgroup` tags, so the select has no direct children that are options. Try the following selector, minus the child `>` selector:

```
$("#testQuestion option").each(function(){...});
```